# I want to separate the contents of the file with \n and put + among the elements

Tags: string, bash

I'm using bash. I need to process a string but it is pretty tricky.

This file contains a list of file like this (just an example):

```
apple.o
orange.bin
banana.o
kiwi.o
```

I want to convert the contents of this file into a string like this:

```
apple.o+orange.bin+banana.o+kiwi.o
```

I want to separate the contents of the file with \n and put `+` among the elements.

It might seem like a stupid question.
But I am new to bash and I don't have much experience with it. I really have no idea about this.

However, I think it would be possible if I use the if statement properly in for loop.

Simple pseudo code (there can be some issues):

```
for line in 0..number_of_line:
     if line notequal number_of_line:
        put content[line] with "+" into result
     else:
        put content[line] into result
```

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `paste`:

```
paste -s -d '+' file
```

Output:

```
apple.o+orange.bin+banana.o+kiwi.o
```

---

See: `man paste`

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash`:

```
str=$(< file)       # Slurp the file into the variable `str`
str=${str%$'\n'}    # Remove the last character if it is a newline
str=${str//$'\n'/+} # Replace all newlines with `+`
echo "$str"         # Print the variable to see its contents
```

Answer (score 0):

A `bash` function that takes a filename as an argument and returns the joined file:

```sh
slurpfile() {
    local IFS=+
    mapfile -t lines < "$1"
    printf "%s" "${lines[*]}"
}
```

Example usage:

```
combined=$(slurpfile input.txt)
printf "%s\n" "$combined"
```

It just reads the file into an array, one line per element, and then joins them together with the correct `IFS` separator between elements.

Answer (score 0):

usually, I use awk for parsing text, since its faster and portable

print all the lines in one line with add `+` with each row :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="+"}1' file.txt
```

to remove the last occurrence of `+` :

```
sed 's/\(.*\)+/\1/'
```

one-line version :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="+"}1' file.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)+/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all newlines by a `+` and restore the last newline.

```
 tr '\n' '+' < file | sed 's/+$/\n/'
```